# How can I minimize brush marks in polyurethane where wood grain meets from different directions?

Tags: wood, finish

Am finishing dining table that has wood grain that meets in center of table and goes in different directions. Using thinned, oil poly, applied with ox-tail brush. Have applied 1 coat. Doesn't look good where grain meets.
How do I apply with the grain, when they go in 2 directions, for a great look?

Comment: I wouldn't think your thinned poly would show much brush grain at all. Are you working it too long? You could try a foam brush.

Comment: Was trying to "go with the grain" where the wood meets. Almost impossible. Have no experience with this.

Comment: Mask over one piece with tape.

Comment: Never looks good after one coat, especially when thinned. Sand lightly, clean off the dust, and reapply. Three coats usually gets pretty smooth.

Comment: I don't use tape that will leave a visible line that is hard to blend. I find going slow and loading my brush heavily with minimal strokes is the best method, a very light sanding between coats then a good wipe down and next coat.

Comment: As said, it's as issue of patience. You can't avoid brush marks on the first coat but with each successive coat, the surface gets flatter and flatter.

Comment: The grain itself doesn't matter, it's that you're changing the direction of the stroke. How much are you thinning it? Are you using a GOOD brush, or a $3 brush? How big of an item are we talking? Is spraying it possible?

Comment: I would browse the [tag:finishing] tag at [woodworking.se], for _dozens_ if not _hundreds_ of tips on finishing.

Comment: *How to **maintain a wet-edge** in the center of a table, in four different directions?* - "Quit while you're ahead." - meaning, you might *not* on your first, second, or third try. And if the wet-edge *isn't*, then you have to stop poking it. - Use a $40 angled brush (with 40y of exp :) and take no longer than four minutes to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would sand the surface with a fine grit paper to remove any brush marks. Wipe it down with denatured alcohol to remove the dust. Get you a foam roller and roll a coat onto the surface. Roll slowly to prevent too many air bubbles. Allow it to dry and put a second finish coat on it. Three coats is standard in the industry. Foam rollers tend to leave a smooth finish overall with no worry of brush marks. You can also add some Japanese Drier to the poly to make it dry faster.

Comment: Does it matter what direction you roll? Wish I could attach pic of the table. Has been such a headache for me.

Comment: After last coat, do I sand again?

Comment: The rolling direction doesn't matter. The poly will self-level on a horizontal surface. The surface should be very smooth after the final coat. Once the poly cures out (2-3 days), I would spray some lemon Pledge on it to help protect the finish.

Comment: I don't like foam to me they create bubbles. I always use very high end brushes, after done clean most the poly out then seal in a mason jar with the bristles covered in thinner or spirits, using this method my 20+ brush(s) have lasted for years.

Comment: "*very* high end brushes" +1. OP said they used an ox-tail brush. Did it say *Purdy* on it...? If it did then they used it wrong.